# "Failed to create table: error while reading data, error message could not parse 'date' as on TIMESTAMP on SQL"

Tags: sql

I tried to create a table on SQL with a dataset I desired, I've succeed with the 4 of them, but then once I tried to create a table within the same dataset, I keep getting error that says "Failed to create table: error while reading data, error message could not parse 'date' as on TIMESTAMP. Any idea what is wrong with that and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Which DBMS/SQL flavor are you using?

Comment: What’s the command you are running to create the dataset?

Comment: well, most likely that your source data has bad format in column "date", the standard format is: 2023-07-04T22:18:54Z (the Z for UTC)

Comment: Thanks, @YairMaron for the information! do you think I can change the date format on the spreadsheet? then import the new .csv file to the SQL again?

Comment: yes, in excel you can create a new field and use this formula: `=TEXT(C2, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")` - assuming your date is in C2 (just change it to the right one)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that your source data has bad format in column "date"

You have 2 options-

1. Fix / change the source date format
2. Convert the format on your DB query

As for option 1, the standard date format is: `2023-07-04T22:18:54Z` (the Z for UTC).

As for option 2, you didn't specify which RDBS (type of database) you're using,
assuming you're using MS-SQL, you can use the `CONVERT()` function, with parameters:

- target_type - should probably be `DATETIME`
- expression - should be the field you want to convert
- date_style - you should select from list* - probably 103

for example:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME, [date], 103)
```

*Here is the list of all formats:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#j-use-convert-with-datetime-data-in-different-formats